# How can I add a class to a title of a view?

Tags: views, 6, theming

I'd like to add a class to the title (H1) of a view, so that a specific style could be applied. This is Drupal 6 with a Zen subtheme.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Views 3, you should be able to click on Style Settings on the field, Customize field HTML.  From there, you can set `H1` as the HTML element or click on "Create a CSS class" to add a class.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Theme Information in your view.
- Copy the code for the entire view in the top level template.
- Create a file named after the most specific suggestion with this code inside in your theme's template folder.
- Add your class to the `H1` element.
- Style to your heart's content in your theme's CSS.

Comment: I'd like to add that in Drupal 6 you will need to have the base template (views-view.tpl.php) in order for the other suggestions to be picked up. They need to be in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the view rewrite the output of title as

```
<div class="H1">[title]</div>
```

then u can do the styling properties for this H1 in your CSS file easily.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do with

```
<div id="my_custom_class">my title</div>
```

another way need to overwrite template files of that view